# How can I use dates as values and along the X axis in RGraph?

Tags: javascript, graph, date, rgraph

I'm trying out the horizontal bar RGraph demo with this code and it works great:

```
var data = [1, 40, 30];
var hbar = new RGraph.HBar('myCanvas', data);
hbar.Set('chart.labels', ['Richard', 'Alex', 'Nick']);
hbar.Set('chart.background.barcolor1', 'white');
hbar.Set('chart.background.barcolor2', 'white');
hbar.Set('chart.background.grid', true);
hbar.Set('chart.colors', ['red']);
hbar.Draw();
```

Is there a way I can use `Date` objects instead of numbers? I couldn't get it to work with stuff like

```
var data = [new Date(1000), new Date(2000), new Date(3000)];
```

Comment: Why do you need to use Date objects? Can you explain what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to display horizontal histograms whose values are dates to show a timeline-like graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you can do something like :

```
var data, dates = [new Date("11/16/2011"), new Date("11/17/2011"), new Date("11/18/2011")], labels = [];
// Get the date from the date objects
for(var i = 0, len = dates.length; i < len; i++) {
    // Data for the graph
    data[i] = dates[i].getDate();

    // Labels for each data entry
    labels[i] = dates[i].getDate() + "/" + dates[i].getMonth() + "/" + dates[i].getYear();  
}
var hbar = new RGraph.HBar('myCanvas', data);
hbar.Set('chart.labels', labels);

/// rest of the code
```

Date object on MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This is only part of the deal, though, as I don't get the nice Date labels on the X axis…

Comment: What do you want to display in the labels? Can you tell clearly?

Comment: Well, I'd like dates instead of numbers — formatted with a format I can define, e.g. "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: Check out the edited answer. You can change the formatting for the date as you wish. Also check out the MDN link on the Date object for the function references.

Comment: Setting the labels like this doesn't work: it sets the name of the horizontal bars. I want the dates to show up along the horizontal axis.

Comment: The values for the horizontal axis are automatically generated from the data specified. You can see the list of available customization options here : http://www.rgraph.net/docs/bar.html#properties.

Comment: Yes, they are automatically generated, and that's the problem: they are numbers instead of dates. We're very close, but I can't award you the 100 points unless we reach a working solution.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet I've modified the RGraph.hbar.js file. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1088914/RGraph.hbar.js . Use this file and use hbar.Set('chart.hlabels', ['l1', 'l2', ... ]); to set the text for the horizontal axis. The changes are from line 592 to 595. Check the formatting based on your inputs. 

P.S. :  The 100 rep bounty is not the only reason we answer questions here. Its because we learn from these as well. ;)